# errors using alias for an awk command

Tags: ssh, awk, alias

I'm attempting to add this alias to my .zshrc but run into errors. I've tried escaping the ==, ", and && values and still no luck. What am I missing?

```
alias broke="ssh -t server@5.555.555.555 tail -f documents/dir/`date -u +%Y%m%d`.log | awk '$2=="ABC:" && int($5)>=26 || int($5)<=-26'"
```

Comment: I'll post some of the errors if necessary. Its just that I tried many iterations and it produced different errors each time.

Comment: you might consider simplifying your examples until you demonstrate the exact problem. "errors using alias", "run into errors", "still no luck" don't help us diagnose the actual problem (even if we might have some educated guesses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have premature execution of your command substitution because your alias is defined using double quotes instead of single quotes, so `date` is executed when your alias is *defined*, not when it is called;
2. Your shell is interpreting your `awk` field references as shell positional parameters and
3. is expanding them *when your alias is defined*;
4. `awk` never sees the double quotes around `ABC:` so it is interpreted as the unset `awk` variable `ABC` (i.e. a null string) followed by an unquoted colon in an unexpected position, which likely throws an `awk` error;
5. As bonus advice, you should really use `$(...)` rather than `` `...` `` because the quoting rules inside are much more intuitive.

To set an alias that includes command substitution and special characters, you should be setting it with single quotes.  There is virtually never a use case where you will want parameter expansion at the time your alias is *set* rather than when it is called.

You can't embed single quotes within single quotes, but that doesn't matter because quotes aren't delimiters by themselves:

```
alias hassinglequotesembedded='echo "It'\''s not really too hard; current date when the alias is executed is $(date)"; echo '"'but the alias was set at $(date)'"
```

There is some highly recommended further reading about quoting types on Stack Overflow:

- [Expansion of variable inside single quotes in a command in bash shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13819996/5419599)

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you're going to run often enough to need an alias, you'll almost certainly be better off if you:

1. write it as a shell script - far less chance of getting lost in nested quotes.
2. `scp` it to `/usr/local/bin` (or somewhere else in the PATH) on your remote server.  Or just write it there in the first place.  Remember to make it executable with `chmod`.
3. just run the script via `ssh` whenever you need it.  `ssh  -t server@5.555.555.555 myscript`.  If you want, you can even put that in an alias:

   `alias broke='ssh -t server@5.555.555.555 myscript'`

BTW, use `$()` rather than backticks.  `$()` is easier to read, easier to nest without problems, and isn't easily confused for single-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was as simple as needing to escape the `$` characters

not working:

```
alias trim="awk '{$1=$1};1';"
```

solution:

```
alias trim="awk '{\$1=\$1};1';"
```